# SQL to update a row with the sum of a value from the row below

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a script which will update a stock level list which has been merged from two stock centres.

A snippet of the data I have;

```
MovementId  ChangeDate           StockLevel AdjustmentLevel
1835        2016-01-24 09:48:56  -29        -15
1725        2016-01-22 11:49:31  -138       -10
1715        2016-01-22 11:12:47  -128       -28
1701        2016-01-22 10:48:47  -100       -5
1532        2016-01-20 19:55:28  -14        -14
1520        2016-01-20 18:14:57  -95        -14
1512        2016-01-20 17:55:37  -81        -15
1338        2016-01-19 17:46:22  -66        -7
```

I am trying to achieve;

```
MovementId  ChangeDate           StockLevel AdjustmentLevel
1835        2016-01-24 09:48:56  -167       -15
1725        2016-01-22 11:49:31  -152       -10
1715        2016-01-22 11:12:47  -142       -28
1701        2016-01-22 10:48:47  -114       -5
1532        2016-01-20 19:55:28  -109       -14
1520        2016-01-20 18:14:57  -95        -14
1512        2016-01-20 17:55:37  -81        -15
1338        2016-01-19 17:46:22  -66        -7
```

Here's what I have so far..

```
SELECT   
movementid,
changedate,
(Lag(stocklevel, 1, 0)  OVER (PARTITION BY   codeid ORDER BY   changedate)) +AdjustmentLevel   AS NewStockLevel,
adjustmentlevel, 
stocklevel as currentstocklevel
FROM   VET_CodeStockMovement_2
where codeid =14877
order by changedate desc
```

The database has around 23000 rows, I will need to run the completed script against each different CodeID.

Comment: please post current data and expected data as text

Comment: You're still not really specifying your criteria as to looping and which records relate to which.  If you just have these three items, just write three updates and run them rather than trying to complicate thigns.

Comment: please send data as text format !!

Comment: Apologies, new to stackoverflow so was unsure how to format!

Comment: dont really understand how youre arriving and your expected result.e.g.  -152 where does that come from?

Comment: StockLevel should equal the SUM of StockLevel from the previous row + AdjustmentLevel of the current row. E.g. -142 -10 = -152

Comment: so where does -167 come from?

Comment: -167 is the sum of -152 + -15

Answer (score 0):

this script will be help to updated data.

**I created a table named as SAMPLETABLE**

```
   IF OBJECT_ID('SAMPLETABLE') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP TABLE SAMPLETABLE
    GO
    Create TABLE SAMPLETABLE
    (
     MOVEMENTID INT,
     CHANGEDATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     STOCKLEVEL DECIMAL(5,2),
     ADJUSTMENTLEVEL DECIMAL(5,2)
    )
```

**Inserted your data in OriginalTable SAMPLETABLE**

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE VALUES(1033,GETDATE(),-14.00,-14.00)
GO
INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE VALUES(1036,GETDATE(),0,14.00)
GO
INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE VALUES(1056,GETDATE(),-5.00,-5.00)
GO
INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE VALUES(1077,GETDATE(),-15.00,10.00)
GO
INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE VALUES(1205,GETDATE(),-30.00,-15.00)
```

**I created tempTable**

> Created new temp table because I updated  data all time row by row. If you don't do this It would be get wrong totals. Created TempTable and Insert original table data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TMPSAMPLETABLE') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE ##TMPSAMPLETABLE
GO
Create TABLE ##TMPSAMPLETABLE
(
 MOVEMENTID INT,
 CHANGEDATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
 STOCKLEVEL DECIMAL(5,2),
 ADJUSTMENTLEVEL DECIMAL(5,2)
)
GO 
INSERT INTO ##TMPSAMPLETABLE SELECT MOVEMENTID,CHANGEDATE , STOCKLEVEL , ADJUSTMENTLEVEL FROM SAMPLETABLE
```

**Update original data**

> this script update original according to sum tempTable
>   ADJUSTMENTLEVEL column by movementid

```
DECLARE @MOVEMENTID INT
DECLARE @STOCKLEVEL DECIMAL(5,2)
DECLARE @ADJUSTMENTLEVEL DECIMAL(5,2)
DECLARE @SUMVALUE DECIMAL(5,2)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR  
FOR 
SELECT MOVEMENTID ,
       STOCKLEVEL ,
       ADJUSTMENTLEVEL
FROM ##TMPSAMPLETABLE ORDER BY MOVEMENTID DESC

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @MOVEMENTID, @STOCKLEVEL, @ADJUSTMENTLEVEL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
  SET @SUMVALUE = (SELECT SUM(ADJUSTMENTLEVEL) FROM ##TMPSAMPLETABLE WHERE MOVEMENTID <= @MOVEMENTID);
  UPDATE SAMPLETABLE SET ADJUSTMENTLEVEL = @SUMVALUE WHERE MOVEMENTID = @MOVEMENTID;
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @MOVEMENTID, @STOCKLEVEL, @ADJUSTMENTLEVEL
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM ##TMPSAMPLETABLE ORDER BY MOVEMENTID DESC

SELECT * FROM SAMPLETABLE ORDER BY MOVEMENTID DESC
```

**Deleted TempTable**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TMPSAMPLETABLE') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE ##TMPSAMPLETABLE
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem with this is that I have 23000 rows to update which is going to take a very long time if I had to enter data row by row. Please see my answer, which i believe will provide a more automated solution.

Comment: you can't entered any data. I created OriginalTable because I dont have a table by containg your data. You will start  Created TempTable  and insert data 

Create TABLE ##TMPSAMPLETABLE (... ...)
GO 
INSERT INTO ##TMPSAMPLETABLE SELECT .. .. FROM YourTable   then run cursor script
I hope I can help you change the question when writing answers. 
The first version of the problem was different

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of using cursors to achieve what I need as this can then be run to update all of the 23000 rows. Although it may take time to run and is not the most resource friendly, it should achieve what I need without the need to manually enter any data/write updates for each row.

```
DECLARE @codeid INT

DECLARE CodeCursor CURSOR FOR (SELECT DISTINCT(CodeId) FROM vet_codestockmovement)

OPEN CodeCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM CodeCursor INTO @codeid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @movementid INT

DECLARE StockCursor CURSOR FOR (SELECT movementid FROM vet_codestockmovement WHERE codeid =@codeid)

OPEN StockCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM StockCursor INTO @movementid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @lagvalue INT

SELECT @lagvalue = temp.NewStockLevel  FROM (
SELECT  (LAG(stocklevel, 1, 0)  OVER (PARTITION BY   codeid ORDER BY   changedate)) + AdjustmentLevel AS NewStockLevel, MovementId
FROM   VET_CodeStockMovement
WHERE codeid =@codeid) temp
WHERE temp.MovementId = @movementid

UPDATE dbo.VET_CodeStockMovement SET Stocklevel = @lagvalue WHERE movementid = @movementid

    FETCH NEXT FROM StockCursor INTO @movementid
END

CLOSE StockCursor
DEALLOCATE StockCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM CodeCursor INTO @codeid
END

CLOSE CodeCursor
DEALLOCATE CodeCursor
```